# Create contract with contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, inheritance, function

I want to create a contract that can create contract itself

I find something like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract DaughterContract {
 string public name;
 uint public age;
 constructor(
  string memory _daughtersName,
  uint _daughtersAge
 )
  public
 {
  name = _daughtersName;
  age = _daughtersAge;
 }
}


contract MomContract {
 string public name;
 uint public age;
 DaughterContract public daughter;
 constructor(
  string memory _momsName,
  uint _momsAge,
  string memory _daughtersName,
  uint _daughtersAge
 )
  public
 {
  daughter = new DaughterContract(_daughtersName, _daughtersAge);
  name = _momsName;
  age = _momsAge;
 }
}
```

but it's only working when I hardcode Daughter contract
And it only works once

I want to create a mother contract that is able to create multiple daughters by calling function

Something like this

[image]

whats should be change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MomContract` deploys a `daughter` contract only on its constructor, which only runs onces, you should have a function you can call several times for you to deploy the `daughter` at will.